# how to avoid the uninitialized value while using the split in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code

```
my $string = "My mother-in-law lives in Europe";
my @words = split(/(-)|\s+/, $string);
```

I expect the result to be like `My`,`mother`,`-`,`in`,`-`,`law`,`lives`,`in`,`Europe` , but I am getting this error

`Use of uninitialized value $_ in string` , when I try to print the array by using foreach .

right now , I am doing with print

```
foreach  (@words)
{
    print "$_" , "\n" if $_;
}
```

Is there a better solution by modifying the split statement itself ?

Comment: @RohitJain I have given the code now

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting this error, see [this](http://codepad.org/ZFY0Aw2E).

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the capture group in the regex that you provide to split and can be seen clearly with `Data::Dumper`.

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'my $string = "My mother-in-law lives in Europe"; 
  my @words = split(/(-)|\s+/, $string); print Dumper(\@words);'

$VAR1 = [
      'My',
      undef,
      'mother',
      '-',
      'in',
      '-',
      'law',
      undef,
      'lives',
      undef,
      'in',
      undef,
      'Europe'
    ];
```

There are two approaches you can use:

1. use `grep` to remove the undef's from the array.

   ```
   grep defined, split /(-)|\s+/, $string;
   ```
2. Use split twice, first for spaces, secondly for hyphens.

   ```
   map { split /(-)/ } split /\s+/, $string
   ```

Comment: I need the hyphen to be captured but not spaces

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to avoid that `if` part after `print`, you can use the regex pattern as in following code:

```
my $string = "My mother-in-law lives in Europe";
my @words = split(/(?<=-)|(?=-)|\s+/, $string);

foreach  (@words){
    print "$_" , "\n";
}
```

This will split on empty string that is followed by `-` or preceded by `-`, and also on whitespace. Thus giving you `-` as separate element, and also avoiding captured groups.

**Output:**

```
My
mother
-
in
-
law
lives
in
Europe
```

Comment: I dont want the space to be captured

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $string = "My mother-in-law lives in Europe";

my @words = split('(-)|\s+', $string); # Not capturing space

foreach  (@words){
    print "$_" , "\n" if $_;
}
```

Output:

```
My
mother
-
in
-
law
lives
in
Europe
```

Comment: see my question correctly I want this output without the if condition at last `print "$_" , "\n" if $_;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add *whitespace* between the hyphen before splitting to make sure they are treated as a single field.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @my_line = ("My mother-in-law lives in Europe");

foreach (@my_line) {
    s/-/ - /g;
    print "$_\n" foreach split;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
My
mother
-
in
-
law
lives
in
Europe
```

Note that you can also use a slice to get just the field you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "My mother-in-law lives in Europe";

print "$_\n" foreach (split /(-)|\s+/, $string)[0, 2 .. 6, 8, 10, 12];
```